# delphi Import dll function with specified entry point

Tags: c#, delphi, winapi, dll, entry-point

**How can I define this function in Delphi ?** I know imports only without entry point and can't find any usefull example :(

That's written in C#

```
[DllImport("dwmapi.dll", EntryPoint = "#131")]
static extern int DwmpSetColorizationParameters(ref DwmColorParams dcpParams, 
bool alwaysTrue);
```

Thanks a lot

Best regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do, although I'm not sure about the `const` for `alwaysTrue`.

```
function DwmpSetColorizationParameters(var dcpParams: TDwmColorParams; 
  alwaysTrue: BOOL): Integer; stdcall; 
  external 'dwmapi.dll' index 131;
```

Comment: Thanks also to David Heffernan for good points (from the deleted answer). I wrote it in this way (stdcall), because I was writing the code from the screen to the laptop and it's a common practice for external calls, so I used it without thinking about it. And with the pointer as a parameter is minor thing.

Comment: @David Heffernan - that's twice you've deleted your answer in favor of mine. If you get to the States, I owe you a pint. :)

Answer (score 1):

The [`EntryPoint`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.dllimportattribute.entrypoint.aspx) field allows the function to be declared with a name other than what the DLL used to export it. If the first character of the value is `#`, then it indicates the ordinal value of the function instead of the DLL's name for it.

Delphi uses two different clauses. If the DLL uses a name different from the one in your code, then you can use a `name` clause:

```
procedure Foo(...); external DLL name 'Bar';
```

But if the DLL doesn't export any name at all, then you can use an `index` clause to tell which ordinal value the function has:

```
procedure Foo(...); external DLL index 131;
```